# Android JSON Parsing Multilanguage Support

Tags: android, json, parsing, utf-8, multilingual

I am trying to parse json values and here is a part of my code. Json parsing works but doesnt support utf-8 multilanguage , there are character problems . For example ç becomes + , ü becomes ! or some others like that . Does anyone know the reason ?

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

Comment: not support means what happen actually?

Comment: I edited the question by giving examples . Some characters returns different values after parsing the values to the android application.

Comment: what are you passing in params?

Comment: A sentence , for example "weather is perfect" , but using some letters belonging to the different alphabets , not just english.

Comment: i think because of that, its not working.

Comment: what should i change to make it work ?

Comment: Which line does the JSON parsing ?

Comment: httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));

Comment: dont enter different alphabets which is not english.

Comment: I edited the code , now it can be more understandable i think.

Comment: So you are not trying to parse UTF-8 JSON values, you are trying to POST UTF-8 JSON, Am I right ?